# Fakes and .net Framework 4.6.1 and System

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-fakes, .net-4.6.1

When setting an OOB default Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 Project, with no tests setup, using the Target Framework of 4.6.1, adding a Fakes assembly to System and setting the following ShimGenerations:

mscorlib.fakes:

```xml
<ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Add FullName="System.Collections.ReadOnlyCollectionBase"/>
    <Add FullName="System.ApplicationException"/>
    <Add FullName="System.IO.Path"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Security.SecureString"/>
    <Add FullName="Microsoft.Win32.Registry"/>
    <Add FullName="Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Activator"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Convert"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Version"/>
    <Add FullName="System.StringComparer"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Threading.Thread"/>
</ShimGeneration>
```

System.fakes:

```xml
<ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Add FullName="System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Diagnostics.Process"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.CookieContainer"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.FtpWebRequest"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.FtpWebResponse"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.IPAddress"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.Dns"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.Mail.MailMessage"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.HttpWebRequest"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.HttpWebResponse"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.WebHeaderCollection"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.ServicePoint"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.Sockets.Socket"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.WebRequestMethods"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.WebRequest"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Uri"/>
</ShimGeneration>
```

The following error occurs:

> 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketClientAccessPolicyProtocol' is obsolete: 'This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.'
>   [some path\TestFakes\UnitTestProject1\obj\Debug\Fakes\s\f.csproj] some path\TestFakes\UnitTestProject1\f.cs
>
> GENERATEFAKES : error : project compilation failed with exit code 1

This appears to only to occur with this configuration.

I am not sure how to work around this since I need to intercept most of the .NET framework calls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling OBSOLETE error in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608309/disabling-obsolete-error-in-c-sharp)

Comment: GSerg - I would typically agree with you but it is occurring during the GENERATION of the Fake. There is no code involved in my example. I have no unit tests or no code in the project. It is just an empty test class and empty test method. I am basically building an empty project. I posted an answer below but it is very clunky and to me it is not acceptable. If there were better support from MS on this tool, there should be a better way to identify these troubled areas with Fakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending a couple of days on this problem, I found the following. This is a problem with the following class "System.Net.Sockets.Socket". I found that removing this shim generation, then removing all of the .fakes assemblies, then removing one of the .fakes files in the/Fakes folder and recreating it with the "Add Fakes Assembly" dialogue, recreates all of the .fakes assemblies based on the .fakes files in the /Fakes folder and allows the code to build.

Since I did not need to fake "System.Net.Sockets.Socket", this was an acceptable solution to successfully building and rerunning my unit tests. This definitely appears to be a problem specifically with this class and the Fakes framework.

I find that the Fakes framework is a good one but needs better support. Things like this are too difficult to troubleshoot and need improvement. To me the above is not an acceptable solution to the overall. I find that if MS would provide better feedback and more verbosity on such a problem as above, a solution to it would be simpler. One should not have to spend days looking at logs, researching on the web and testing when a simple message such as "This class is unsupported for Shim Generation" would suffice.